# Bootstrap carousel fill window height after nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, height, carousel

I'm trying to get the carousel to fill up the rest of the browser window height. i currently have the nav at the top then the carousel under with a height set of 100% but instead of fill the rest of the space it adds the height of the nav below. I need the nav + carousel to equal the height of the browser. any ideas? this is the url im working on - http://pies.koru.firebrand.co.nz

Cheers

Comment: Why not add an anchor tag at 'carousel-inner' and then have the page scroll to it as soon as it loads?